# Trying to uninstall Visual Studio. InstallCleanup.exe does not exist and running install doesn't create it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Something is broken on my machine and Visual Studio 2019 will not update or install. [this article][1] recommends running the below exe to clean your system of all Visual Studio installations:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe
```

However, it does not exist. In this case, that article says to run the VS installer, get to the Workflows tab, and then close the installer to make the exe appear, but it doesn't.

I am using 2019 Community Edition. Anyone know where I can get this exe?

Answer (score 5):

As is the case many times, it's only until *after* I ask a question that I try something I hadn't thought of, and that was to search the entire `Microsoft Visual Studio` folder and I found it here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\InstallCleanup.exe
```

I ran it and was able to successfully install 2019.

Background: I tried updating 2019 one day when the update failed and I was no longer able to build any of my applications. Updates and full reinstalls would fail saying that it could not access one of the package files. I had to fall back to 2017 and had been using it since this occurred back in February. I decided I wanted 2019, so I went the full uninstall route, but could never find the above-mentioned exe until now. I hope this helps all the others who have been having this issue.

This all occurred during a 2019 update one d
Others have experienced this as well, but I found no solutions. I will probably just mark this as answer if VS installs properly.

Comment: Save my life!!! I also cant find InstallCleanup.exe in office document... and cant upgrade / uninstall because of lack of package! Thanks very much!!!